# disable all UITabBarItems on launch of iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

My requirements is that whenever the application launches, i need to show a company Logo fill screen image view with the UITabBar at the bottom of screen with all UITabBarItems disabled.

The user will continue to see this logo view till he chooses to click on any of the tabbaritems and then the related view controller comes up

I've tried setting the `[tabItem setEnabled:enableState];` to FALSE in the appDelegates `application:didfinishlaunchingwithoptions:` just before the below but still did not get the above behaviour:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Can you pls suggest how this can be achieved?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

well we have one tricky way for this,simply first time statically set uiimageview(yr splash screen view ) from xib at some view controller  of yr tab bar(just for taking screenshot purpose only) then  u can get a screenshot of your tab bar with your uiimageview(splash screen image) by pressing home button and lock button from device.

Use that screenshot png image as yr splash screen uiimageview(i.e. Default.png in above answer) with big frame so user can not touch our real tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    defaultImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]]; // enter name of image with your company logo
    defaultImageView.frame =self.window.bounds;

    [self.window addSubview:defaultImageView];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self continueLoading]; //Load what do you want to load


    return YES;
}
```

And than, ofter all loaded run this method:

```
- (void) removeImageFromScreen
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:defaultImageView];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    defaultImageView.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it helps me show the default.png for some time. however my requirement is to show the uitabbarcontrol along with this image with no tabbaritems selected (I'm not sure how to do this). only after the player clicks on any tabbaritem, the screen for that tabbaritem should appear